# PostgreSQL - Check if column value exists in any previous row

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a problem where I need to check if an ID exists in any previous records within another ID set, and create a tag if it does.
Suppose I have the following table

```
    | client_id | order_date | supplier_id | 
    | 1         | 2022-01-01 | 1           |
    | 1         | 2022-02-01 | 2           | 
    | 1         | 2022-03-01 | 1           | 
    | 1         | 2022-04-01 | 3           | 
    | 2         | 2022-05-01 | 1           | 
    | 2         | 2022-06-01 | 1           | 
    | 2         | 2022-07-01 | 2           |
```

And I want to create a column with a "is new supplier" tag (for each client):

```
| client_id | order_date | supplier_id | is_new_supplier|
| 1         | 2022-01-01 | 1           | True
| 1         | 2022-02-01 | 2           | True
| 1         | 2022-03-01 | 1           | False
| 1         | 2022-04-01 | 3           | True
| 2         | 2022-05-01 | 1           | True
| 2         | 2022-06-01 | 1           | False
| 2         | 2022-07-01 | 2           | True
```

First I tried doing this by creating a dense_rank and filtering out repeated ranks, but it didn't work:

```
with aux as (SELECT  client_id,
        order_date,
        supplier_id
FROM table)
SELECT *, dense_rank() over (
            partition by client_id
            order by supplier_id
        ) as _dense_rank
FROM aux
```

Another way I thought about doing this, is by creating an auxiliary id with client_id + supplier_id, ordering by date and checking if the aux id exists in any previous row, but I don't know how to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

Instead of dense_rank, you can just use row_number and on your partition by add supplier id..

Don't forget to order by order_date

```
with aux as (SELECT client_id,
                    order_date,
                    supplier_id,
                    row_number() over (
                        partition by client_id, supplier_id
                        order by order_date
                        ) as rank
             FROM table)
SELECT client_id,
       order_date,
       supplier_id,
       rank,
       (rank = 1) as is_new_supplier
FROM aux
```